# find the max temperature of each month in a year using map reduce program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

My code seems correct to me but on cmd its not giving correct output, please anyone help me to find problem in the code. It runs properly but the output is wrong:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class temp {
    public static class Mymapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable,Text> {

        public void map(Object key, Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

            int month=Integer.parseInt(value.toString().substring(16, 18));
            IntWritable mon=new IntWritable(month);
            String temp=value.toString().substring(26,30);
            String t=null;
            for(int i=0;i<temp.length();i++){
                if(temp.charAt(i)==',')
                        break;
                else
                    t=t+temp.charAt(i);
            }
            Text data=new Text(value.toString().substring(21, 25)+t);
            context.write(mon, data);
        }
    }

    public static class Myreducer extends  Reducer<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable,IntWritable> {

        public void reduce(IntWritable key,Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            String temp="";
            int max=0;
            for(Text t:values)
            {
                temp=t.toString();
                if(temp.substring(0, 4)=="TMAX"){
    if(Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(4,temp.length()))>max){
                        max=Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(4,temp.length()));
                    }
                }
            }

            context.write(key,new IntWritable(max));
        }

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "temp");
        job.setJarByClass(temp.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Mymapper.class);

        job.setReducerClass(Myreducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);

        }
}
```

Input file:

> USC00300379,19000121,TMAX,-78,,,6,
>   USC00300379,19000131,TMAX,-133,,,6,
>   USC00300379,19000111,TMAX,127,,,6,

Output to this code is:

> 12 0
>   13 0
>   11 0

Comment: Here: "19000121" : 1900 is year, 01 is month, 21 is day. How come you are expecting '12' as a day? There seem to be some misunderstanding. If you want maximum temperature for each day, then your expected output is: 21 0, 31, 0 and 11 127 (since 127 > 0)

Comment: This answer is tested. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/34677353/5678086

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you have shifted index by one (should be substring(15, 17) instead of substring(16, 18)), but i can't figure out why based on the input file snipped (maybe you missed something here?)

Due to the shifted index you receive months 12, 13, 11 instead of 01, 01, 01. And you receive 0 as max temperature due to shifted index "TMAX" isn't presented at the beginning of the string.

Suggestions:

1. You have comma separated csv file, so don't use substring. You can use value.toString().split(",") to receive parts of your record.
2. See what parts do you need (date and temperature).
3. Fetch month from date part using substring method.
4. You don't need TMAX part in the reducer. So you can only produce IntWitable, IntWritable (Month, Temperature) as mapper output.
   5.Get rid of TMAX checks in reducer (use only temperature IntWritable values).

Suggestions:
Don't create  Text and IntWritable instances in mapper and reducer every time. You can make it instance fields and use set methods (it optimizes memory)

Comment: i did it with substring(15,17) its giving same wrong output @adushenin

Answer (score 0):

Following code will fix the issue. Replace your Mymapper and Myreducer with the below code

```
public static class Mymapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable,Text> {
    public void map(Object key, Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        String line = value.toString();
        String[] elements = line.split(",");
        int month=Integer.parseInt(elements[1].substring(4,6));
        Text data=new Text(elements[3]);
        context.write(new IntWritable(month), data);

    }
}

public static class Myreducer extends  Reducer<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable,IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(IntWritable key,Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int temp=0;
        int max=0;
        for(Text t:values)
        {
            String tmp = t.toString().trim();
            if(!tmp.equals("")) {
                temp=Integer.parseInt(tmp);
                if (temp > max) {
                    max = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        context.write(key,new IntWritable(max));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take first record:

```
USC00300379,19000121,TMAX,-78,,,6,
```

In this record `19000121`:

```
1900 - Year
01 - Month
21 - Day
```

So, the expected output should be:

```
21 0 (Since -78 < 0)
31 0 (Since -133 < 0)
11 127 (Since 127 > 0)
```

To achieve this, you need to make following changes in your code.

**map() method**:

- Parsing of the months

  Change:

  ```
  int month=Integer.parseInt(value.toString().substring(16, 18));
  ```

  To:

  ```
  int month=Integer.parseInt(value.toString().substring(18,20));
  ```
- Initialization of string

  Change:

  ```
  String t=null;
  ```

  To:

  ```
  String t=""
  ```

**reduce() method:**

- Comparison of strings

  Change:

  ```
  if(temp.substring(0, 4)=="TMAX"){
  ```

  To:

  ```
  if(temp.substring(0, 4).equals("TMAX")){
  ```

With these changes, I got the following output:

```
11      127
21      0
31      0
```